# For loop not firing - Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, for-loop, fs

For whatever reason, my `for` loop is not firing. This command is supposed to return the command of a user mentioned. `!commands @rusty` would trigger the embed of my command. (The JSON file is not empty, line 6 works perfectly. My JSON file looks as follows: https://hastebin.com/awezatexob.json (I cannot post it here as well as this code.

```
fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, "../jsonFiles") + "/customCommands.json", "utf-8", function(err, data) {
  if (err) throw err;

  var arrayOfObjects = JSON.parse(data);

  if (arrayOfObjects.commands.length === 0) return message.reply("No custom commands found.");

  for (let i = 0; i > arrayOfObjects.commands.length; i++) {
    console.log("Hello"); // does not fire
    if (message.guild.id !== arrayOfObjects.commands[i].guild_id) return message.reply("No commands in guild.");
    if (user.id !== arrayOfObjects.commands[i].user_id) return message.reply(user.username + " has no commands in this guild.");

    fs.writeFile(path.join(__dirname, "../jsonFiles") + "/customCommands.json", JSON.stringify(arrayOfObjects, null, 2), "utf-8", function(err) {
      if (err) throw err;
      const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
      .setColor(0x08F258)
      .setAuthor("Custom Commands for " + user.username, message.author.avatarURL)
      .addField(arrayOfObjects.commands[i].command_name, arrayOfObjects.commands[i].command_reply)
      return message.channel.sendEmbed(embed);
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: `for (let i = 0; i < arrayOfObjects.commands.length; i++) {`

Comment: @JazZ Okay so that's good, it is now firing. However it is returning the first `if` within my `for` loop. (I logged `message.guild.id` where my previous log was and it returned the correct id as within the JSON file, so why is it that it is giving me this `No commands in guild` when they clearly match?

Comment: You'd better create a new question.

Comment: By the way, you could log the `arrayOfObjects.commands[i].guild_id` to be sure you compare to the right value.

Answer (score 0):

```
i > arrayOfObjects.commands.length;
```

should be

```
i < arrayOfObjects.commands.length;
```

IE: you have the condition reversed.

Comment: Okay so that's good, it is now firing. However it is returning the first if within my for loop. (I logged message.guild.id where my previous log was and it returned the correct id as within the JSON file, so why is it that it is giving me this No commands in guild when they clearly match?

Answer (score 0):

In your `for` arguments, you are saying that `i` has to be greater than `arrayOfObjects.commands.length`, when it was supposed to be opposite, like this

```
for (let i = 0; i < arrayOfObjects.commands.length; i++)
```

So your for looping will be running while `i < arrayOfObjects.commands.length` is true